# Database.update(lstOpportunity, false) in Batchable class execute() method

Tags: apex, batch

I have a class which implements Database.Batchable, Database.AllowsCallouts. In the execute method, when I am using just update lstOpportunity the update goes through but when I use Database.update(lstOpportunity, false) it does not work.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Opportunity>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
  public Iterable<Opportunity> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
      // Do a soql on opportunity.
      return lstOpportunity;
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity){
    if(lstOpportunity != null && lstOpportunity.isEmpty() == false){
      // Do a callout and save the result in a lstOpportunityToUpdate
    }

    if(lstOpportunityToUpdate != null && lstOpportunityToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
     // Here if I use "update lstOpportunityToUpdate;" it works 
     // but "Database.update(lstOpportunity, false)" does not work.

     }
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What does "not work" mean here? Do you receive an error?

Comment: `// but "Database.update(lstOpportunity, false)" does not work.` this line in your code performs a partial save and does not throw an exception if there are any errors. You must handle the errors in the return value yourself or they silently pass on through.

Comment: What I meant to say was, the update DML operation does not go through. If the there were any errors, the update DML operation would rollback entire transaction which is not happening.

Comment: As Mark Pond states, the false parameter means that no exception is thrown and thus no rollback occurs.  See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm).